# Javascript: Optimizing insertion of large text with many colors

Tags: javascript, html

I have a pre environment in my HTML, and I'm using Javascript to insert a large string to it:

```
$my_environment.innerHTML = my_large_text;
```

The string is about 100,000 characters long. When the string is composed of clean text only, everything is good. However, when I try to add colors to many of the characters (around 1/3 or so) and I do it by wrapping each individual letter by

```
<span style="background-color:some-color;"></span>
```

there's a noticeable delay ,during which the browser window - and in case of Firefox, the whole browser - is stuck.

The pre environment itself is of limited size and uses overflow, so only a small portion of it actually has to be painted during the text change.

What is causing the delay and is there anything possible to fix it?

1. Maybe I can use another environment instead of pre, but I'd rather not.
2. The colors are not concurrent; think of the letters that have to be colored as distributed randomly.
3. I'm willing to consider any better way to assign colors to letters instead of simply wrapping them with the span environment, if it will speed things up.

Comment: Can we see the code that is wrapping the text elements as that is most likely where the bottle neck is?

Answer (score 0):

One optimization step would perhaps be to use 'class' tags rather than 'style' tags. If you use pre-defined css classes you may, depending on the exact scenario, cut down on rendering time.

Another approach could be to have all your letters rendered in monochrome but in span elements with id's. You can then use Javascript to colour the letters that need to change.